# RegEx in Java and JS behaves different?

Tags: java, javascript, regex, gwt

I have a big problem with JavaScript RegEx match:
On the Java side, a RegEx splitting expression behaves different then on the JS side. I've stripped it down to the following example, maybe you know the root cause?

Teststring:
`test == 1`.

I want the `== 1` to match (I will use this as a splitter lateron, but does not matter for my question).

Stripped Regex:
`([=\s]+).*?(?:[=]|\z)+`

Result on java side (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) matches: `== 1`

Result on JS side (http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) matches: `==` and `=`

WHY? How can I make the regex JS to behave the same as the Java side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not support `\A` start and `\Z` end of string anchors and is hence forced to end the match on `=`. Use the `$` end of line anchor instead.

***EDIT** :*

There's only a single match there too. If you look at the [code](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and add `alert(m);` to it

```
alert(m); // ["== 1", "=="]

var s = "Match at position " + m.index + ":\n";
for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
  s = s + m[i] + "\n";
}
alert(s);
```

`m[0]` gives you the actual match (just like `Matcher#group(0)` in Java) and `m[1]` the first *group capture*.

***EDIT** : (Difference between Java and JavaScript's **String.split()** methods)*

- Unlike Java, JavaScript's *split()* returns any capturing groups specified in the delimiter regex in the resulting array. So, you need to make your first regex group non-capturing as `(?:[&=\\s]+)?`.
- With Java's *split()* method, trailing empty strings are not included in the resulting array. In your JavaScript code, you would have to ignore them yourself. But, given the nature of your input string (boolean conditions) you can safely drop the last element since, your input string would always end with a delimiter.

Comment: Ok that fixes the issue with the line-end, using `([=\s]+).*?(?:[=]|$)+`. But further: why do I get 2 matches in JS, I only want 1 match as in Java?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing the split wrong? I want to use the regex to split a string into tokens, and the matches should act as dynamic deliminator. Looking at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html, I see I'd get .split[]: `[0]: test,
[1]: =, [2]: 1`. But I only want `test`. Why do I get 3 results, and not only the `test` string?

Comment: What's the complete input string that you're trying to split here? If it's long just make one up that covers all delimiters.

Comment: My strings look like `test1 == 1 && test2 == 2`, and I want to extract `test1` and `test2` here. In Java I'd just run a `value.split(REGEX)` with `REGEX=([&=\\s]+)?[=<>]+?.*?(?:[&=]|$)+`. This would just give me an array with `length = 2`, but in JS this does not work...

Comment: @membersound Please, check update. The `String.split()` methods of Java and JavaScript have a few subtle differences in the way they work.